# R Adding polygon name data to point data

Tags: r, gis

I have two sets of data: Point level data and polygon data.  I am aiming to add the name of the polygon into which a pint is located as an extra column on the point level data.

I have found and used the code below utilising the sf library.

```
new_point_data <- point_data %>% mutate(
  intersection = as.integer(st_intersects(geometry, polygon_data))
  , area = if_else(is.na(intersection), polygon_data$Name[intersection])
```

This works in 90% of cases, however when a point intersects a polygon the code does not bring any data back.  Which I'm assuming is because it will return two (or more) values and cannot determine which to use, how can I update this to select any value e.g. the first?

Comment: can you please provide a reproduceable example? ... like one polygon and 3 points: one within, one at the border and one outside of the polygon. This way you make sure we are on the same page solving the exact issue... also you could inlcude the used libraries aswell, since it makes it easier to help

Comment: one way to responde your assumption of returning more than one value: use the function on a vector of one value that only returns the output of the function => this way you see the exact output in the console